# Angular table row component

Tags: angular

I am using angular to create a table row component that creates rows from an array of objects. However, I keep getting a file to compile error when trying to populate the data in the table.

Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

[image]

*table.component.html*

```
<table id="users">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor = "let column of headers">
        {{column}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  
    <tr *ngFor = "let row of rows">
      <td *ngFor = "let column of headers">
        {{row[column]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  
  </table>
```

*table.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent {
  headers = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "Gender", "Country"];

   rows = [{
         "ID": "1",
         "Name": "Rahul",
         "Age": "21",
         "Gender": "Male",
         "Country": "India"
      },
      {
         "ID": "2",
         "Name": "Ajay",
         "Age": "25",
         "Gender": "Male",
         "Country": "India"
      },
      {
         "ID": "3",
         "Name": "Vikram",
         "Age": "31",
         "Gender": "Male",
         "Country": "Australia"
      },
    
    
   ]

}
```

Comment: I have pasted your code in the stackblitz link below. It seems to render fine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qujkrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Feel free to edit it for the exact code error.

Answer (score 0):

Your didn't specify the types for headers and rows.
It could be the root of issue as compiler doesn't know that it's an object type. Also it's not very flexible solution. Let's replace {{row[column]}} with function call {{getCellData(row, col)}} and implement the logic in ts file.
Also you can review source code of existed solutions like ngx-datatable to understand how to implement really flexible and configurable grid

Comment: why would we want to call a function in template? It will be called over and over and over on each change detection.

Comment: @AT82 , as I see the only one reason - to have working code in 10seconds.
After that the developer SHOULD optimize it. Totally agree that fn call in angular template is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have strict mode applied to your project, which is GREAT! :) Therefore we should correctly type our data (as we always should do despite strict mode or not!)

So first of all, create a model for your Array, I prefer interfaces:

```ts
export interface RowData {
  ID: string;
  Name: string;
  Age: string;
  Gender: string;
  Country: string;
}
```

Cool, now we can use that to tell Angular in your component, or rather TypeScript, that our array looks like `RowData`:

```ts
rows = [...] as RowData[];
```

Now to the `headers`... we need to tell that the array we are providing presents keys of our model `RowData` so we can use that in the template without getting that error:

```ts
headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Country'] as Array<keyof RowData>;
```

Now we are good to go!

Comment: Could you please explain the reason to use `as` syntax?
Why not to use `rows: RowData[] = [...]` ?
Thanks

Comment: `rows: RowData[] = [...]` works just as good, it's the same thing. I have just opted to use `as`, but really it doesn't matter which one you choose to go with :)